System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file '.'
i get that Exception on my code
did try to change the paths
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var credentialPath = "serviceAccountKey.json";
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("coaching - app - 7602b - firebase - adminsdk - qwg5j - fd1ddc277b");


You are passing an arbitrary string instead of the credential file path to the GoogleCredential.FromFile function. Assuming that your file is actually located at "serviceAccountKey.json", you should pass the argument as such:
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(credentialPath);

